# How do I do an internal curved corner?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Sorry for the very dumb question. I just don't know how to do this. How can I make the side of this object follow the curve in my reference image in the background?

Comment: Try using proportional editing

Comment: Yep, that's a good solution too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way instead:

- Extrude down:

[image]

- Bevel:

[image]

- Mirror, rework the topology with the knife (<kbd>K</kbd>) and some join (<kbd>J</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: duhhhh!  Yes!! Of course. Thanks for the smack round the head! :)